# Apache jena-fuseki server refuses connection when running tests from a shell script

Tags: django, pytest, jena

I'm unittesting an application that uses apache-jena-fuseki from python backend with sprql. I didn't find any means for using an in-memory jena test-db, thus I decided to start a test-fuseki-server from the shell script that runs my tests.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x
cd jena/apache-jena-fuseki-3.13.1
nohup jena/apache-jena-fuseki-3.13.1/fuseki-server --update --file sandbox_2019-11-20_10-57-04.nq / >/dev/null 2>&1 &
export pid=$!
cd -  
JENASERVERPASSWORD="<myJenaPw>" \
JENASERVERUSERNAME="rommi" \
DBPASS="" \
DBUSER="" \
DBHOST="" \
DBNAME='db.sqlite31' \
DBENGINE="django.db.backends.sqlite3" \
JENAHOST="http://localhost:3030" \
JENADATABASE="{0}/ds/{1}" \
python manage.py test 
kill -9 $pid
```

Every time when I run the script above I get "Connection refused error" errno 111 in the middle of the execution even though my fuseki-server is up and even though the previous tests succeeded. I've also tried without the last command (kill -9), but it does not help.
If I run the above commands manually everything goes fine.
What can be the reason ?

Comment: Try capturing the server log file.

Comment: @AndyS I just run the same tests manually and using my shell script. The 1st run succeeded and the second failed. Both server logs were similar, no errors, just the same warnigs like this: [2019-11-26 08:07:30] Fuseki     WARN  SPARQL Update: Unrecognized request parameter (ignored): output
[2019-11-26 08:07:30] Fuseki     WARN  SPARQL Update: Unrecognized request parameter (ignored): format
[2019-11-26 08:07:30] Fuseki     WARN  SPARQL Update: Unrecognized request parameter (ignored): results

Comment: It is quite possible to saturate the OS when running client and server on the same machine. TCP connections don't get cleaned up by the OS fast enough especially if the client is using a new connection every HTTP call. A simple way to test for this is add a short pause between tests.  Also - run "netstat -t".